# Why message passed through intention doesn't appear in selected activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to send text message to activity (selected by user) using intent with action.
When I click on button there dialog of application list appear (gmail, messaging...)and when I select app for sending SMS-messages for example, there no message that I passed using intention - just empty field.
This is method that works on button click:

```
public void onSendMessage(View view){
    EditText messageView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String messageText = messageView.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(GetActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, messageText);
    Intent chosenIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Send message...");
    startActivity(chosenIntent);
}
```

I tried to use `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` instead of `GetActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE` - it's better - now I can send message to *Google Translate*, but still not to *messaging* apps (it prompts to start new message which is empty).

Comment: Maybe you're looking for: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#EXTRA_TEXT

Comment: @emandt for what ? I didn't get what should I do.

Comment: You're using "....EXTRA_MESSAGE" and you can try to change it with "Intent.EXTRA_TEXT"

Comment: @emandt it's better, now I can send text to Google Translate, but when I click Messaging there dialog appeared with Cancel and New Message options, New Message starts empty message.

Comment: Each App could uses a different KEY as you just seen between previous EXTRA_MESSAGE and the EXTRA_TEXT. it depends of that specific App, version and Minifacturer changes. There are some common rules that a developer (who created the Messenger app you're trying to use) could follow while creating its App, but it's just a convention.

Comment: WhatsApp could use EXTRA_MESSAGE, Telegram could use EXTRA_TEXT, the stock SMS Messenger could use a 3rd one... Unfortunately it's near impossible to be sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

If just want you to share only text, use below code.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "**This is my text to send.**");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Below link will briefly help you to share with other contents,

https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send